# IOS: searchbar in tableview

Tags: xcode, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am creating a searchbar in a tableview but I have problems with this method delegate because I fill the table view with array inside another array...I show my code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
ProgramAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ProgramAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[tableData removeAllObjects];// remove all data that belongs to previous search
if([searchText isEqualToString:@""] || searchText==nil){
    [myTableView reloadData];
    return;
}
NSInteger counter = 0;
for(NSString *name in appDelegate.globalArray )
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
    NSRange r = [name rangeOfString:searchText];
    if(r.location != NSNotFound)
    {
        if(r.location== 0)//that is we are checking only the start of the names.
        {
            [tableData addObject:name];
        }
    }
    counter++;
    [pool release];
}
[myTableView reloadData];
}
```

You can see the code "for(NSString *name in appDelegate.globalArray )" it don't work because I fill the table view with elements of arrays inside this global array, I make an example

In a row of my table view there is a uitableviewcell and inside it there are four label;
I write these label with string of this globalArray but in this way:

```
[cell.label1 setText:[[appDelegate.globalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1]];
[cell.label2 setText:[[appDelegate.globalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:2]];
[cell.label3 setText:[[appDelegate.globalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:3]];
[cell.label4 setText:[[appDelegate.globalArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:4]];
```

then in delegate method for searchbar the code "for(NSString *name in appDelegate.globalArray )" don't work, How can I change my code?

**** I DON'T SAY THAT I WANT TO CHECK ONLY LABEL1 FOR THE SEARCH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `globalArray` is an array of arrays. So the loop should be something like.

```
for(NSArray *rowArray in appDelegate.globalArray )
{
    for ( NSString *name in rowArray ) {
        // Do your processing here..
    }
}
```

**Using `tableData`**

In your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, do this

```
[cell.label1 setText:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:1]];
[cell.label2 setText:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:2]];
[cell.label3 setText:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:3]];
[cell.label4 setText:[[tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:4]];
```

In your `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`, `return 1`;

In your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`, `return [tableData count];`

You should include a method that will reset the search data to the original content when the user stops searching.

```
- (void)resetSearchData {
    // Get appDelegate first.

    self.tableData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:appDelegate.globalArray];
}
```

Comment: now no problems, but does not search, when i write a name inside searchbar, elements remain the same in Tableview

Comment: Two things here – `[tableData addObject:name];` should be `[tableData addObject:rowArray];` and you should replace `appDelegate.globalArray` with `tableData` in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: first thing ok; second thing I do this in loadview: [tableData addObjectsFromArray:appDelegate.globalArray];

Comment: `loadView` is only called once when the controller has its view property set to nil. So it has little role in filtering results. I don't understand why you are loading data from `appDelegate.globalArray` when you are saving your search results in `tableData`.

Comment: then what can I do? What should you do?

Comment: Added an edit to explain my view on this. Let me know if I am wrong in some of my assumptions here.

Comment: ok...but now my code don't entry in the firts loop "for(NSArray *rowArray in appDelegate.globalArray )"  why???

Comment: Can you check if your global Array is empty? It's hard to tell how my changes are affecting the rest of the code. If it is not critical data, you can send it to me. I can help you better then.

Comment: ah no ok....I solve it, but I write a nslog inside first loop as
NSLog(@"rowarray:%@", rowArray); and it show my arrays correctly but in my list I see nothing yet

Comment: It's all ok my code don't like this "NSString *name in rowArray" but if I declare NSString out of loop it work fine...thanks a lot